# Как правильно открыть файл в PHP на IIS?

Tags: php, iis

Нужно открыть файл в IIS.
Такой код открывает без проблем

```
$filename = 'C:/web/files/test.txt'';
file_get_content($filename);
```

А вот этот код вызывает ошибку:

```
$filename = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/files/test.txt';
file_get_content($filename);


Warning: file_get_contents(C:\web/files/test.txt): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in
```

Пробовал такой вариант:

```
$filename =  addslashes($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '\\files\\test.txt');
file_get_content($filename);
```

Но тоже ошибка.

Как правильно открыть этот файл в IIS?
Windows Server 2008 R2
PHP 5.6

Comment: А в  Warning точно `teXt.txt` написано?

Comment: Это уже моя опечатка. Везде test.txt. Я просто заменил реальное название файла на test.txt для упрощения чтения

Comment: Вместо слешей/обратных слешей попробуйте константу `DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR` http://php.net/manual/ru/dir.constants.php